# How to treat the dispute?

Tags: the-buddha, mindfulness, history, texts, practice

I have recently started studying the teachings of Buddhism, so I have a lot of questions that I can't find an answer to yet.
Help me understand Buddhism better. Thanks.
What types of disputes are there?
What does the teaching of Buddhism say about disputes?
Is it necessary to take part in disputes?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by dispute. Are you talking about disputes of suttra, disputes of philosophy, dispute in some story of Buddha, etc.

Comment: @HomagetoManjushri, I mean, about different kinds of disputes. 
Dispute with the boss.
Dispute in the family
Dispute in some story of Buddha
And others...
In what cases is it possible? In what cases is it impossible?

Comment: Didn't I already ask about this and the mods freaked out? They just had to protect us babies from the suffering that dispute brings, just like The Bodhisattva's father. Hopefully, the mods have stopped the silly helicopter parenting that is totally out of alignment with the Dhamma.

Answer (score 2):

The following sutta quotes are helpful.

From [Sutta Nipata 4.11](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.11.than.html):

> "From where have there arisen quarrels, disputes, lamentation,
> sorrows, along with selfishness, conceit & pride, along with
> divisiveness? From where have they arisen?    Please tell me."
>
> "From what is dear there have arisen quarrels, disputes, lamentation,
> sorrows, along with selfishness, conceit & pride, along with
> divisiveness. Tied up with selfishness are quarrels & disputes. In the
> arising of disputes is divisiveness."

You have things dear to you and your friend has things dear to him or her. "Dear" here means clinging or attachment. For e.g. you cling to your religion and political ideology, while your friend clings to his or her religion and political ideology. This difference causes the arising of quarrels and disputes.

The best thing to do is just agree to disagree, out of friendliness or kindness. That should settle the quarrel.

In [MN 128](https://suttacentral.net/mn128/en/sujato), the Buddha gave this advice:

> For enmity in this world
> is never settled by enmity.
> **It’s only settled by love:**
> this is an ancient principle.
>
> Others don’t understand
> that our lives must have limits.
> The clever ones who know this
> **settle their quarrels right away**.

The word that was translated as "love" above is *[avera](http://dictionary.sutta.org/browse/a/avera)* in Pali, which is translated by some dictionaries as friendliness or kindness.